# Dot Product between 2 Mx3 Matrices in Eigen C++ ( Similar to np.dot(x.transpose, y) )

Tags: c++, numpy, eigen, dot-product, broadcasting

I`m trying to find the fastest way to compute a MxN matrix with dot products in c++ using Eigen.

*3rd Update: This is part of a Maya 2018 plugin ( For which I'm using visual studio 2018 with the toolset v141 which is what they recommend apparently to work properly with their devkit )*

Lets say we have 2 Matrices:
A(3,5812) and B(3,23686)

What I'm looking for in Numpy is achieved using:
result = np.dot(A.T, B) which creates a result matrix of 5812 x 23686

## Np.Dot takes 394 ms

So my progress so far:

Loop in loop method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)A.cols(); i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < (int)B.cols(); j++) {

        result(i, j) = A.col(i).cwiseProduct(B.col(j)).sum();

    }

}
```

## Process completed in: 891 ms

and using Eigen broadcasting:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)A.cols(); i++) {

        result.row(i) = A.col(i).replicate(1, B.cols()).cwiseProduct(B).colwise().sum();

}
```

## Process completed in: 844 ms. #

```
result =  A.transpose() * B
```

## Process completed in: 690 ms. #  ( Update 3 .. 170ms)

I used OpenMP to multithreaded the loops, but I removed that in the code above for readability.
There has to be a faster way to do this properly maybe without using loops at all? I`ve been searching for a couple of days now... So, in the end, I decided to post here...
Thanks!

---

Second Update:

Managed to reduce the time to 170ms using A.transpose() * B... with openblas, and using MatrixXf instead of Xd..since for this particular implementation that precision is fine... still working on it trying various optimizations...

---

Third Update:

So for the sake of making things more clear I will post the function I'm currently working on...

Python version:
def getCorrespondences(X, Y, Cx, Cy, Rx):

```
timer = time.time()
X_ = np.dot(Rx, X - Cx)
Y_ = Y - Cy
ab = np.dot(X_.T, Y_) # each cell is X_i dot Y_j
xx = np.sum(X_*X_, 0)
yy = np.sum(Y_*Y_, 0)
D = (xx[:, np.newaxis] + yy[np.newaxis, :]) - 2*ab
idx = np.argmin(D, 1)
elapsed_time = time.time() - timer
print (elapsed_time)
return idx
```

## Python computes this in 1.377s

And my current c++ implementation

```
DWORD tcStart1 = GetTickCount();

X.transposeInPlace();
Y.transposeInPlace();
Cx.transposeInPlace();
Cy.transposeInPlace();
Rx.transposeInPlace();

int vtxCountX = (int)X.cols();
int vtxCountY = (int)Y.cols();

MatrixXf X_ = Rx * (X - Cx.col(0).replicate(1, vtxCountX));
MatrixXf Y_ = Y - Cy.col(0).replicate(1, vtxCountY);

MatrixXf ab = X_.transpose() * Y_;

MatrixXf xx = X_.cwiseProduct(X_).colwise().sum();
MatrixXf yy = Y_.cwiseProduct(Y_).colwise().sum();

MatrixXf D(vtxCountX, vtxCountY);

MatrixXf::Index index;
VectorXi idx(D.rows());



#ifdef _OPENMP
int a, b;
if (vtxCountX > vtxCountY) { b = threads / 4; a = threads - b; }
else { a = threads / 4; b = threads - a; }
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(a)
#endif

for (int i = 0; i < vtxCountX; i++) {
    #ifdef _OPENMP
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(b)
    #endif

    for (int j = 0; j < vtxCountY; j++) {
        D(i, j) = xx(i) + yy(j) - 2 * ab(i,j);
    }
    D.row(i).minCoeff(&index);
    idx(i) = (int)index;

}

DWORD tcTotal1 = GetTickCount() - tcStart1;
//cout << idx.transpose() << endl;
cout << "Correspondence computed in: " << tcTotal1 << endl;

return idx;
```

## This seems to the job in 906 ms with MatrixXf, and 1297ms with MatrixXd

I still need to figure out how I can squeeze more speed out of this since this function will end up getting fired hundreds of times.

I will try other things proposed in the comments... or if you guys have any other suggestions I`m all ears :)... I ended up casting to float since the result is a bunch of indexes... so I don`t need precision... the function basically computes distances and figures out some point correspondences, for Procrustes alignment.

I ended up using loops at a certain point instead of eigen replicate and cwise broadcasting since that seemed to be slower:/. Anyway I hope this gives more context. Cheers

---

Update 4...

```
    int vtxCountX = (int)X.rows();  int vtxCountY = (int)Y.rows();
    MatrixXf X_ = (X - Cx.row(0).replicate(vtxCountX, 1)) * Rx.transpose();
    MatrixXf Y_ = Y - Cy.row(0).replicate(vtxCountY, 1);
    MatrixXf ab = Y_* X_.transpose();
    MatrixXf xx = X_.cwiseProduct(X_).rowwise().sum();
    MatrixXf yy = Y_.cwiseProduct(Y_).rowwise().sum();
    MatrixXf D(vtxCountX, vtxCountY);
    MatrixXf::Index index;
    VectorXi idx(D.rows());

    #ifdef _OPENMP
    int a, b;
    if (vtxCountX > vtxCountY) { b = threads / 4; a = threads - b; }
    else { a = threads / 4; b = threads - a; }
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(a)
    #endif
    for (int i = 0; i < vtxCountX; i++) {
        #ifdef _OPENMP
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
        #endif

        for (int j = 0; j < vtxCountY; j++) {
            D(i, j) = xx(i) + yy(j) - 2 * ab(j,i);
        }
        D.row(i).minCoeff(&index);
        idx(i) = (int)index;
    }
```

## This does the job in 469 ms... 17 faster than my original implementation... and ~3 times faster than numpy...

Comment: The loop approach might work better if you save the transpose of the matrices (i.e. 3 values per row). That way you should reduce the number of page-faults.

Comment: What's wrong with simply `result = A.transpose() * B`?

Comment: result =  A.transpose() * B .. ~700ms... still slower than numpy :/

Comment: How are you benchmarking this? Did you ensure that matrices are initialized with similar values? (No uninitialized memory, no NaNs/subnormals, ...) Did you compile your eigen code with `-O2 -march=native -fopenmp -DNDEBUG`? Are you using `Matrix3Xd` or `MatrixXd`?

Comment: And regarding what @BennyK said, it may indeed be more efficient to store `A` in row-major format (or directly store `A.transpose()` in column major order).

Comment: I was using MatrixXd in the tests..

Compiler flags:
/permissive- /GS /Qpar /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\include" /I"H:\Visual Studio\eigen-3.3.7" /I"H:\Visual Studio\libigl-master\include" /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "NTPLUGIN" /D "REQUIRE_IOSTREAM" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /arch:AVX2 /Gd /Oi /MD /openmp /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\Test.pch" /diagnostics:classic (Compiling for Maya 2018)
Also Installed OpenBlas -Shaved 20ms

Comment: Are you able to switch to gcc or clang? MSVC often has trouble optimizing Eigen code. Also: Put any relevant information into the question not into the comments.

Comment: And can you try `Eigen::MatrixX3d At = A.transpose(); result = At * B;` -- maybe also with `MatrixXd` instead of `MatrixX3d` (a more optimal solution would just do block-wise transposes (if in fact you can't change how `A` is stored in the first place)). Finally, do you really need `result` explicitly? E.g., if you actually want to compute `result * x` it is much more efficient to compute `A.transpose() * (B * x)`

Comment: chtz, thanks a lot for the input, I posted more info in the hope it will give proper context. I`m using MSVC cause that seems to be the suggested way to go for Maya 2018 plugins...i`d probably have to do some more research to see if their devkit will work properly with gcc or clang... not sure. I also posted the code.. so you can see how those variables flow.. Im still need to write the rest of the code to figure out if and where do I need to transposed those input matrices... depending on the rest..

Comment: Are you actually interested in `D(i,j)` or just the closest neighbors `idx`? For the latter, have a look at [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Nearest_neighbour_search).